# Push all values from object to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I'm just starting as a programmer. Can someone help me with this problem? All I have so far is:

```
var myArr = [];
for (var k in input) {
    myArr.push(
```

Am I on the right track?

Write a loop that pushes all the values in an object to an array.

```
input: {two: 2, four: 4, three: 3, twelve: 12}
output: [2, 4, 3, 12]
```

Comment: You, you're on the right track, just push `input[k]` to the array

Comment: and do a check for `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @user1950929 in modern ES5 code that should almost never be necessary.  jQuery manages perfectly well without...

Answer (score 2):

Without loop:

```
const input = {two: 2, four: 4, three: 3, twelve: 12};
const myArr = Object.values(input);
console.log(myArr);
// output: [2, 4, 3, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you writing it in javascript native, use the push() function:

for example:

```
var persons = {roy: 30, rory:40, max:50};

var array = [];

// push all person values into array
for (var element in persons) {
    array.push(persons[element]);
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

input = {two: 2, four: 4, three: 3, twelve: 12}

const output = Object.keys(input).map(i => input[i])

[2, 4, 3, 12]

This will help you to find exact output.

This link will provide you more information
https://medium.com/chrisburgin/javascript-converting-an-object-to-an-array-94b030a1604c

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArr = []; 

var input = {two: 2, four: 4, three: 3, twelve: 12};

for (var k in input) { 
    myArr.push(input[k]);
}
alert(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.input[k]` is what you want

```
var data = {input: {two: 2, four: 4, three: 3, twelve: 12}}, myArr = [];

for(k in data.input) myArr.push(data.input[k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#values):

```
var myArr = _.values(input);
```

It's a very useful library, and only 5.3k when gzipped

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the `for in` loop the variable `k` gets assigned the next property name in the object `input`, so you have to push `input[k]`. For the case that the object has properties from its prototype and you only want to push the objects own properties to the array (that is probably what you want to do) you should use `hasOwnProperty`.

```
var input: {two: 2, four: 4, three: 3, twelve: 12}
var myArr = [];
for (var k in input) {
//  if( input.hasOwnProperty( k) ) { //not necessary
    myArr.push( input[k] );
//  } 
}
```

Be aware that `for in` loops over the object in arbitrary order, i.e., the order of the items in the array might not be what you expect it to be.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

**EDIT:** as Alnitak has mentioned in a comment to the OP it is probably not necessary to use `hasOwnPropery()` nowadays.

Comment: `.hasOwnProperty` is unnecessary.  Anyone who extends `Object.prototype` without doing it the safe ES5 way (via `Object.defineProperty`) to make the extension non-enumerable deserves all they get.